# How to Access Activity(except mainactivity) from Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I created my test project where i code to communicate between two fragments but actully I want to access activity from fragment.
Here is code to connect fragment to fragment, its working absolutely right without any error but now i want to change this code to connect activity from fragment instead of fragment to fragment communication.
So Please change this code to access activities from fragment. I stuck on this issue for than a week.So Guys please resolve this.

here is my mainaactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentA.FragmentAListener, FragmentB.FragmentBListener {
private FragmentA fragmentA;
private FragmentB fragmentB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    fragmentB = new FragmentB();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_a, fragmentA)
            .replace(R.id.container_b, fragmentB)
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onInputASent(CharSequence input) {
    fragmentB.updateEditText(input);
}

@Override
public void onInputBSent(CharSequence input) {
    fragmentA.updateEditText(input);
}
```

Here is my FragmentA.java:

```
 public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
private FragmentAListener listener;
private EditText editText;
private Button buttonOk;

public interface FragmentAListener {
    void onInputASent(CharSequence input);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    editText = v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    buttonOk = v.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CharSequence input = editText.getText();
            listener.onInputASent(input);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void updateEditText(CharSequence newText) {
    editText.setText(newText);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof FragmentAListener) {
        listener = (FragmentAListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement FragmentAListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    listener = null;
}
}
```

Here is my FragmentB.java:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
private FragmentBListener listener;
private EditText editText;
private Button buttonOk;

public interface FragmentBListener {
    void onInputBSent(CharSequence input);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

    editText = v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    buttonOk = v.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CharSequence input = editText.getText();
            listener.onInputBSent(input);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void updateEditText(CharSequence newText) {
    editText.setText(newText);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof FragmentBListener) {
        listener = (FragmentBListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement FragmentBListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    listener = null;
}
 }
```

Here is my Fertilizers.java file which i want to access from FragmentA.:

```
 public class Fertilizers extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
List<FertilizerData> myFertilizersList;
FertilizerData mFertilizersData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fertilizers);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Fertilizers.this, 1);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    myFertilizersList = new ArrayList<>();
  mFertilizersData = new FertilizerData("Urea Fertilizer","Urea is a concent","Rs.1900",R.drawable.urea);
    myFertilizersList.add(mFertilizersData);
  myFertilizersList.add(mFertilizersData);  }
 }
```

please write here a block of code to call Fertilzers Activity from FragmentA, I,ll be very thankful to you.

Comment: Fragments cannot be "converted" to activities. You need to set up a callback from fragment B to activity, and then call a (public) method from activity to fragment A, which seems to be the case in your code.

Comment: If I create a new activity names as fertilizersActivity than how i can access from fragmentA?

Comment: Look at your own code. You create fragment A with fragmentA = new FragmentA() so you can later call its methods (if public) with fragmentA.YourMethod();

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getActivity()` in your fragment gives you the calling activity so if `MainActivity` started your fragment then you would do

```
(MainActivity(getActivity())).something_from_your_main_activity
```

Comment: Thanks for your sincere attention ,@tyczj can u explain it with working block of code?so that i can clearly understand your valueable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by itself regarding this issue.

FragmentHome.java class should look like this:

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment  {



private Button button;


public FragmentHome(){

}

public interface OnMessageReadListener
{
    public  void onMessageRead(String message);
}

 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.bn);


  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Fertilizers.class);
          intent.putExtra("some","  some data");
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
    return v;

}
}
```

FertilizersActivity.java should look like this:

```
public class Fertilizers extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fertilizers);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null){
        if(bundle.getStringArrayList("some") !=null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"data:" + bundle.getStringArrayList("some"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
}
```